# ASP.NET MVC Routing - It redirects when I don't want it to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a simple search engine with the following URLs:

```
"/" - this is the homepage with the search textbox and submission button.
"/search?q=" - this is where the results will appear. The query is the q= parameter.
```

This is my search controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class SearchController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Start() {           
        SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
        return View( model );
    }

    /// <summary>Performs a search.</summary>
    /// <param name="q">The search query.</param>
    /// <param name="a">The search action ("I Feel Lucky", etc).</param>
    /// <param name="page">The results page number.</param>
    public ActionResult Search(String q, String a, String page) {
        return View();
     }
}
```

Finally, this is my routing table:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {         
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "SearchQuery",
        "Search", // match "http://mysite.com/Search"
        new { controller = "Search", action = "Search" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "SearchStart", // Route name
        "", // match "http://mysite.com/"
        new { controller = "Search", action = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

However, when I make a HTTP request for `http://mysite.com/Search?q=foo` I get a 301 redirect to `http://mysite.com/Search/` where a 404 is returned. My `SearchController`. `Search` action is never invoked.

What do I need to do to allow for what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in what you've shown that would cause this problem.  Is this the entire application?

MVC doesn't redirect by itself.  You either have to tell it to redirect, or use some kind of attribute or filter that redirects in certain conditions.

Comment: I changed the rule to use "/S" instead of "/Search" and it works. I've removed every reference to "Search" in my application and for some reason I still get a 301 when I type it into the address bar. I've no idea where it's coming from, but it's a start.

Comment: 301 is a permanent redirect which is normally cached by the browser. You might have redirected the URL permanently sometime before and now it is cached. Have you tried to clear your browser's cache?